# Too many arguments for method filter

Tags: apache-spark

What I tried do here is to filter the rows where `log_type = "1"`
This is my code:

```
val sc1Rdd=parDf.select(parDf("token"),parDf("log_type")).rdd

val sc2Rdd=sc1Rdd.filter(x=>x,log_type=="1")
```

but the error code showed:

> parDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [action_time: bigint,
>   action_type: bigint ... 21 more fields] sc1Rdd:
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] =
>   MapPartitionsRDD[865] at rdd at :186 :188: error:
>   too many arguments for method filter: (f: org.apache.spark.sql.Row =>
>   Boolean)org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
>          val sc2Rdd=sc1Rdd.filter(x=>x,log_type=="1")

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is long_type a column name ?

Comment: Thank you for all of your helps. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the dataframe to RDD 
you can simply filter or where as

```
val result = parDf.select(parDf("token"),parDf("log_type")).filter(parDf("long_type")===1)

parDf.select(p===1)arDf("token"),parDf("log_type")).where(parDf("long_type")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you~ and I made the changes to "val sc2Rdd=sc1Rdd.filter(x => x(1)==1)" it works now. thank you for help